# MYSQL IN Query With Comma Separated Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an MYSQL stored procedure used to find the results from a table of customers.

```
find_customers(IN customer_ids VARCHAR(255), OUT customer_data JSON)
BEGIN
   SELECT 
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(main_table.id, main_table.name)
    ) INTO customer_data
   FROM
        customers AS main_table
  WHERE
    main_table.id IN(customer_ids);
   
END
```

**Problem**:

Argument customer_ids passing to store procedure always a string which holds the ids as comma separated, but  I am not sure how I can translate customer_ids `'1,2'` INTO `1,2` and pass that value IN clause.

I tried a number of ways but it did not work for me

1. `main_table.id IN(REPLACE(customer_ids, "'", ""))`
2. `main_table.id IN(TRIM(BOTH "'" FROM customer_ids))`
3. `main_table.id IN(SUBSTRING_INDEX(customer_ids, ",", 100))`

Sample Table customers

| id | name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gul | 030385285 |
| 2 | Tehsin | 030385285 |
| 3 | Qayoom | 030385285 |
| 4 | Idrees | 030385285 |

When customer_ids '1,3' pass to store procedure then expected result should be as

```
[
   {
        "1": "Gul"
    },
    {
        "3": "Qayoom"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you share sample input tables and expected output for the query executed inside your stored procedure?

Comment: `.. WHERE FIND_IN_SET(main_table.id, customer_ids) ..`

Comment: @lemon added the sample table and expected output

Comment: Thanks, @Akina! I tried FIND_IN_SET and it worked for me.